# Is the sum of the probabilities derived by sampling from a distribution greater than any other sum of sampled probabilities as $n$ tends to infinity?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let $\mu$ be a probability distribution.

Assume to generate a set of observations $\{ x_0, \dots, x_n  \}$ by sampling from this probability distribution. Fix $r>0$ a real number and consider the series

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{n} \mu( B(x_i, r) )$$

where $B(x_i, r)$ is the Euclidean open ball centered at $x_i$ of radius $r$.

Is is true that for any probability distribution $\mu_1 \ne \mu$ we have that there exists a $ n_1 \in N$ s.t. for almost all samples from $\mu$ of cardinality $ n_2 > n_1$ we have

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n_2} \mu( B(x_i, r) ) \ge \sum_{i=0}^{n_2} \mu_1( B(x_i, r) 
)$$
?

Comment: It seems that you mix up distribution and probability measure/space. Please recall these notions and rewrite your post afterwards. Further, one usually uses $x_0, \dots, x_n$ for realisations. At the moment, you used the variable $X_1$ twice ...

Comment: @Stockfish Sorry for that, is it better now?

Comment: It's almost perfect! Using \mathbb{N} yields $\mathbb{N}$. Both sums are running from $0$ to $n_2$, I guess you want sth else.